# Minimum possible size of generating set of $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is it true that the group $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^m$ cannot be generated by less than $m$ elements?

Comment: The span of $n$ vectors has at most $p^n$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{m}$ is a vector space of dimension $m$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.  Any single generator generates a 1-dimensional subspace.  If you want to span the entire vector space, you certainly need $m$ linearly independent vectors.